# Visual Studio Online - operations failed getUser List

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We are trialing a test migration of a project on `TFS 2010` (on prem) to `#visual-studio-online` using `#OpsHub`  . During the migration phase at the user mapping window we are getting the below error message.

> 2015-07-08 15:10:49,916 [4] ERROR Error : The operation has timed out 
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   webRequest, WebException& webException)

I am not able to find much information on-line about this error. I tried doing the migration as a `TFS` administrator and as a domain user who has project admin access to the project but still get these time out errors.

I saw online a user upgraded to `#OpsHub 1.3` from `1.2` to overcome this issue which I tried but still doesn't help. Do we need to open any other ports for this to work apart from 80 and 443? Any suggestion as to how to over come this issue?

Comment: Please send us log files from C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs directory. zip all the files and send us on ovsmu@opsHub.com

Comment: Any updates on this? Have you sent us logs on given email id?

Comment: Hi Gaurav,Yes I just emailed the logs to ovsmu@opsHub.com

Answer (score -1):

From the logs we find out that error is about time out from your local tfs server.

Server Error : TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server tfs.nextdigital.com\Next Digital.
Technical information (for administrator):
  The operation has timed out

Here you need to work with your tfs admin to increase timeout parameter of your tfs.

Following thread might help you in this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ablock/archive/2008/09/16/increasing-the-time-out-time.aspx

Thanks & Regards,
OpsHub Support